# How to split column into two

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have dataset which looks like this:

[image]

And I want to convert into something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve it in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using <kbd>WRAPSROWS( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2` --> **Exclusively Applicable To MS365 Current Channel**

```
=WRAPROWS(A1:A10,2)
```

---

• Formula used in cell `F2` --> **Applicable To Excel 2010+ onwards**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$10,COLUMNS($F$2:F2)+(ROWS(F$2:F2)-1)*2),"")
```

---

• Formula used in cell `I2` --> **Applicable To Excel 2021+ onwards**

```
=INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)/2,2))
```

---